# How to get value from dynamic checkbox and textbox

Tags: jquery, ajax

Hey guys i have a problem to get value from my checkbox and textbox which i added dynamically. This is my checkbox and textbox display 
[image: here]

This is my html code to call my checkbox and textbox

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" id="pilihtambahan" style="margin-top: 5px;">

</fieldset>
 $.ajax({
            url: host+'/skripsi3/phpmobile/tambahbarang.php',
            data: { "id": getacara},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data, status){
                console.log(data);
                $.each(data, function(i,item){ 

            $("#pilihtambahan").append('<input class="tambahsewa" type="checkbox" value="'+item.idbarang+'" name="cektambah" id="'+item.idbarang+'"><label for="'+item.idbarang+'">'+item.namabarang+' @ Rp.'+item.harga+',-</label><input type="text" id="'+item.idbarang+'" name="jumsewa" placeholder="Jumlah Sewa '+item.namabarang+'"><hr>').trigger("create");    

                });


            },
            error: function(){
                console.log("error");
                //output.text('There was an error loading the data.');
            }
        });
```

and this is my tambahbarang.php

```
<?php
session_start();
include "config.php";
$idacara=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["id"]);
//$arr = array();
$result=mysql_query("select * from barangsewa where id_acara='$idacara'");
if (!empty($result))
{
    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $fetchbarang[] = array
        (   
            'idbarang' => $row['id_barang'], 
            'namabarang' => $row['namabarang'],
            'harga' => number_format($row['harga'], 0, ',', '.'),
            'kosong' => "tidak"     
        );
    }
}

mysql_close($con);

header('Content-Type:application/json');
echo json_encode($fetchbarang);
?>
```

Maybe someone can help me.
Thank You and Have a nice day!! Cheersss!!

Comment: You'd get the value just as you would from *any* `input` element.  Where are you trying to get the value?  How is it not working as expected?

Comment: hey @David Thank you for your fast response, i mean if checkbox have been checked and texbox has been have value

Comment: So are you just looking for the jQuery `.val()` function?  `$(someSelector).val()` would return the value for whatever the selector identifies.  Or if you're looking for the values in PHP, they'd be in whatever method sent them to the server from the form, such as `$_GET` or `$_POST`.  It sounds like what you're looking for is some sort of introductory tutorial in either jQuery or PHP...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#pilihtambahan input[type=checkbox]:checked, #pilihtambahan input[type=text]').each(function(index, element){
    console.log($(element).val());
});
```

Answer (score -1):

One thing I have always run into with dynamically generated content is that when I assign my jquery events to certain page elements, they don't actually exist at the time of assignment.  A way to fix this is to add a callback after dynamically generating the page elements.

Thanks and good luck,
-Kyle

Comment: What does this have to do with the question?  Also, side note, in jQuery this problem is very easily solved by using event delegation with the `.on()` function, binding to a common parent element instead of the dynamic element(s).